# DX TreeList - how to make Popup menu on Tree Nodes?

Tags: menu, popup, devexpress, treelist

i use DevExpress TreeList. Does anyone can put some example, how to create simple popup menu and add this menu on Nodes in TreeList..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
treeListObject.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

contextMenuStrip1 - here is simple standard .NET context menu strip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the devexpress popup menu control then check out this tutorial: http://www.itjungles.com/devexpress/how-to-easily-create-popup-menu-for-devexpress-treelist